# Can't find scanner

Tags: scanner

HP Photosmart C5250 works fine as printer.
How do I get Simple Scan &/or Scanlite to find the HP C5250 scanner? Both Applications report "Sorry no devices found". All-in-One printer scanner is on LAN USB port.
System Settings has no scanner icon.

Comment: What is the output of `lsusb`? What says `sane-find-scanner`?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the appropriate drivers for your device on this website:

http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install_wizard/index.html